# Hosted Frontend: Nextjs on vercel and backend: Strapi on Amazon lightsail VPS

Tags: next.js, web-hosting, strapi, vps, vercel

I have hosted Frontend: Nextjs on vercel and backend: Strapi on Amazon lightsail VPS. On the front end local its working fine but on the vercel after hosting. only for the images it is automatically calling "https" whereas my backend is on "http".
But the normal text data is coming up as it is. Both places i have used same env variable.

PS: I have put env file on vercel with http://ip address

The following the way i have put image on src.

```
<section className="row px-md-5 my-5 px-3">
          <section className="col-md-7 my-5 ">
            <div className="dine-experience">
              {diningSection?.allImages?.data.map((dining: any) => {
                return (
                  <div key={dining.id} className="image">
                    <img
                      src={
                        process.env.PUBLIC_BASE_URL + dining?.attributes?.url
                      }
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </section>
```

Comment: Is `PUBLIC_BASE_URL` properly declared in Vercel's [environment variables](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables#declare-an-environment-variable)?

Comment: Yes it is declared.Although later i just put it as a constant and checked, again same happened ,the value is http://imagelink but its coming up https://imagelink which is 404.